# Multiple sub queries for each result, how to make faster?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I'm doing a query like this:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''
    SELECT person.id, person.name
    FROM person
    JOIN vehicle ON vehicle.owner_id = person.id
    WHERE person.age >= 18 AND vehicle.model = %s
    ''',
    ('Toyota Auris',)
)
people = [dict(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

And then for every person, I fetch their vehicles' informations:

```
for person in people:
    cursor.execute(
        '''
        SELECT vehicle.id AS id, vehicle.name AS name, vehicled.model AS model
        FROM vehicle
        JOIN person ON person.id = vehicle.owner_id
        WHERE person.id = %s
        ''',
        (person['id'],)
    )
    person['vehicles'] = [dict(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

But this vehicle fetching is extremely slow, as I have more than 1 million people and 100,000 vehicles registered. Is there any way to make the second query faster?

So what I want is all `person` objects who own a vehicle matching to a particular model, and *all* of their vehicles, regardless of the vehicle's model.

Comment: It is not clear what you want the result to be. In the first you build a `people` list and in the second a `person` dictionary. A single query will suffice but what is the use case?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto `people` is a list of dictionaries, in the second I am looping over those dictionaries with `for person in people:` and thus update every "row" (`dict` object) in the `people` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try fetching first the people having a Toyota Auris then doing a double join on the vehicles. All of this fits in  one query. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT v1.id, person.id AS pid, v2.id AS vid v2.model AS model FROM vehicle AS v1 JOIN person ON v1.owner_id = person.id JOIN vehicle AS v2 ON v2.owner_id = person.id WHERE person.age >= 18 AND v1.model = 'Toyota Auris';
```

Comment: But this doesn't fetch all vehicles for a person, right? It only fetches the ones matching the provided model

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen You could fetch "all vehicles for all person that have the provided model" in just one query. The idea is good, you just need to change your query to get it

Comment: You are right, I've made the corresponding changes, this query should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to test in a bit before accepting, but this seems good. Didn't know you could multi join like this

Comment: If this is still not fast enough, you could consider declaring an index on the field owner_id of the vehicle table in order to speed up the second join.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
 cursor.execute(
    '''
    SELECT person.id, person.name
    FROM person
    WHERE person.age > 17
    '''
)
people = [dict(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

and

```
 for person in people:
    cursor.execute(
        '''
        SELECT vehicle.id AS id, vehicle.name AS name, vehicled.model AS model
        FROM vehicle
        WHERE vehicle.owner_id= %s and vehicle.model = %s
        ''',
        (person['id'],'Toyota Auris',)
    )
    person['vehicles'] = [dict(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```